# What is a better alternative to comparing string.tolower?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

from my past experience and stackoverflow, I learned that String.ToLower() is bad in performance.
Now I have the following issue, I need to filter out or do a specific action when specific words are in a giant list.

Old approach, which I want to fix:

```
if (input.Any(i => i.ToLower() == "alle" || i.ToLower() == "all" || i.ToLower() == "none") 
{
    // do something
}
```

I was thinking of using a hashset, but I am questioning the performance and how it handles the case sensitivity, I basically dont care about the case sensitivity. Does it make sense for me to use the hashset?

my current suggestion as a solution:

```
var unwantedInputsSet = new HashSet<string> {"alle", "all", "none"};
if (input.Any(i => i => unwantedInputsSet.Contains(i))) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Is there any better alternative to this or not.
Do you have any ideas how to approach this better?

Comment: `i.ToLower() is "alle" or "all" or "none"` - c# 9 pattern matching - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements

Comment: though typically you use `string.Equals` instead of `==` if you want to specify you don't care about the case sensitivity eg. `string.Equals(i, "alle", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-6.0#system-string-equals(system-string-system-stringcomparison)

Comment: Hashset is overkill and unlikely to make it faster. Just use Rand Random's suggestion above. Or are you trying to make it more readable?

Comment: Since you want to improve performance you should only use a hashset if the set of unwanted words has a considerably larger size than 3. Three `if` checks using @RandRandom 's suggestion will always be faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass [comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) to the `HashSet`, for example [`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase?view=net-6.0):

```cs
var unwantedInputsSet = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) {"alle", "all", "none"};
if (input.Any(i => unwantedInputsSet.Contains(i))) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Or, as suggested in comments, use pattern matching:

```cs
if (input.Any(i => i.ToLower() is "alle" or "all" or "none") 
{
    // do something
}
```

Which should be [turned by compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WcBBADYMCyAFAMoAuUAJYA7AOakhASlIBeAHySAdABUIAGQgB3GFG4yhAZ1IAiAIZs2ME6WimLbG3ZMiII6wG5CAXyA===) into code similar to yours (though `ToLower` should be called once).

As for performance - it can be highly depended on the actual data and you should measure it using expected datasets. For small search set `HashSet` can be performing worse than several comparisons like:

```
var cmpr = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
if (input.Any(i => string.Equals(i, "alle", cmpr) || string.Equals(i, "all", cmpr) || string.Equals(i, "none", cmpr)))
{
    // do something
}
```

For such benchmarking I recommend looking into [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the code to be maximally performant, do the string comparisons using `string.Equals()` with a `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` parameter.

If you want to make the code more readable and you don't care so much about performance, you can use a simple extension method to compare a string against a number of target strings:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool EqualsAnyOf(this string value, params string[] targets)
    {
        return targets.Any(target => target.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Then you could write your code like this:

```
if (input.Any(item => item.EqualsAnyOf("alle", "all", "none")))
{
    // ...
}
```

If you wanted to get really fancy you could also write an `AnyEqualsAnyOf()` extension method:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static bool EqualsAnyOf(this string value, params string[] targets)
    {
        return targets.Any(target => target.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    public static bool AnyEqualsAnyOf(this IEnumerable<string> sequence, params string[] targets)
    {
        return sequence.Any(item => item.EqualsAnyOf(targets));
    }
}
```

And then your code would just be:

```
if (input.AnyEqualsAnyOf("alle", "all", "none"))
{
    // ...
}
```

I personally wouldn't think it's worth doing that unless you find yourself writing this sort of code fairly often, but it's certainly an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `IEqualityComparer<T>` when declaring a `HashSet<T>`.

```cs
static readonly HashSet<string> unwanted =
    new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "alle", "all", "none" };
```

Also, I would make this a static readonly field to a void repeated creation.

The advantage of the HashSet solution is that it can be  easily extended to more cases. It also allows you to read the unwanted words from a configuration file.

Since C# 9.0 you can use [Target-typed `new` expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new). If you are using a version prior to C# 9.0:

```cs
static readonly HashSet<string> unwanted =
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { "alle", "all", "none" };
```

Usage:

```cs
if (input.Any(i => unwanted.Contains(i))) 
{
    // do something
}
```

without `ToLower()`!